# How do I prove that this equation of arbitrarily many variables is true?

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for every positive and odd integer "x" there exists a unique set of positive integers ${k_1, k_2, ... ,k_I}$ and positive integer "I", such that the following equation holds: ${3^Ix + 3^{I-1}+ 3^{I-2}2^{k_1}+3^{I-3}2^{k_1+k_2}+...+3^{I-I}2^{k_1+...+k_{I-1}} = 2^{k_1+...+k_I}}$. I tried to rewrite it as a series which did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: Show us that attempt, even if it led nowhere.

Comment: I just thought that all terms on the LHS excluding the first two could be expressed as a sum from j=1 to "I" of a_j where a_1 is 3^(I-2) * 2^(k_1) and a_j+1 is expressed recursively as a_j+1 = (a_j * 2^(k_j+1)) / 3 which I think is wrong.

Comment: Since the $k_i$s are all positive, and $I$ is positive, I would wager that this is not true. Consider $x=2$. We know that for all nonnegative integers $z$, $3^z$ must be odd. On the LHS of the equation, we have a bunch of even terms (multiplied by nonzero powers of 2) and a $3^{I-1}$ term. Even + odd + even + even + ... + even must be equal to odd. But the RHS is a power of 2, which is even.

Comment: You are correct, I noticed that I had forgot to mention that x has to be an odd integer, my bad.